# C# Problems with getting the form to close with the Esc key is pressed

Tags: c#

I'm having problems for some reason with trying to get my form to close when the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is pressed. This form also has an *Exit* button as well and when I put code down in the *Exit* button event handler, it doesn't work, so I resorted to making a separate event handler to hold it, and it still does not work.

This is what I have:

```
private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void FormName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first enable `KeyPreview` of your windows form. Go to form property and set the `KeyPreview` to `true`. Your code should work then.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `Cancel` button of the form to `buttonExit`. It's a property on the `Form`. Then you can get rid of all that code.

Comment: This is a preferable way of doing it in your scenario. To uncover why `KeyDown` event solution doesn't works, see [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx).

Comment: @Sinatr, yes of course `KeyPreview` needs to be leveraged. I'm just saying there is a much more reliable way of getting the same job done; no need to reinvent the wheel here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right.
Maybe you are not mapping the keydown event of the form to your event handler method on the form design.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the issue relates to what on the form has the focus, because this control will be the one that recieves the keypressed event not the form its on.

however if you set up using the 
[Form.CancelButton Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx)

then this hard wires itself into the esc key automatically

Comment: as AccessDienied says in his answer it you want to keep your handler the way it is the KeyPreview  command will instruct the form to monitor the keys being pressed on which over control has the focus

Answer (score 0):

You may try set *KeyPreview* property of your form to *true*: otherwise your form will not 
proceed KeyDown events when you've got keyboard focus on a control within the form.

You may modify your buttonExit button as well: set its property *DialogResult* to *Cancel* 
in order to perform a click on Escape pressing.